# В чем проблема получения Push (FCM) на Android 11 (api 30)

Tags: android, firebase, push, fcm

Push отправляется с backend. На всех устройствах уведомления приходят. Но на `Galaxy Z Fold2`, `Galaxy S20`, `Galaxy Note 10lite` не приходят, их объединяет то, что на них стоит Android 11

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, в настройках надо найти и отключить что-то такое:

> [image: скриншот]

Comment: Отключено энергосбережение

Answer (score 0):

Если всё ещё актуально. Предположим что бэкенд это firebase admin sdk. Во первых, чтобы уведомления приходили точно, и обрабатывались в onMessageReceive вам нужно послать не notify а, data уведомления. Так же вам необходимо указать приоритет посылки. Могу дополнить кодом админки  написанной на шарпе.
Прикладываю код на шарпе. Часть от админки для отправки.

```
 public static async void FCMPUSH()
    {
        var registrationTokens = new List<string>
    {
        "some token1",
        "some token2",
    };
        var message = new MulticastMessage
        {
            Data = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "data", "some str" },
            { "time_stemp", "some_time" },

        },
            Android = new AndroidConfig
            {
                Priority = Priority.High
            },
            Tokens = registrationTokens,
        };
        var firebaseMessagingInstance = FirebaseMessaging.GetMessaging(app);
        var batchResponse = await firebaseMessagingInstance.SendMulticastAsync(message).ConfigureAwait(false);
        Console.WriteLine(batchResponse);
    }
```

Использовал библиотеку Firebase Admin sdk от гугла. Это реализация для массовой рассылки. Попробуйте так же запустить проект с отладкой. Поставьте точку останова на onMessageReceived. На всякий случай, может вы не сделали. Если приходят data push, то уведомление само по себе не генерируется. Нужно создавать notification вручную.

Comment: делал через `data`, без `notify`. Безрезультатно

Comment: Обновил свой ответ. Приложил код для отправки пуша с компа. Так же прочитайте текстовое дополнение. Опять таки, если всё ещё актуально.

Comment: Самостоятельно генерировал уведомлвения. На моём `Xiaomi Note 8T` уведомления отображались, но всех приведенных `Samsung'ах` - нет

Comment: А токен на самсунгах генерируется? Пробовали таргетирование по этим устройствам делать? Прям с консоли firebase